# How to determine homotopy equivalence of wedge sum?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology

I am very stuck on the following problem despite my repeated attempt to prove it.  The problem is from Topology II book of Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences from Springer:

Let M and N be positive dimensional closed manifolds.  Prove that the wedge sum $M \vee N$ is not homotopy equivalent to any closed manifold.

How can I prove it?  I literally have no idea..

Comment: Consider the homology groups of $M\vee N$

Comment: Please check out the meta-post on asking a good question: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question  In particular you should avoid "no clue" questions, because it suggests a lack of effort. You say that you've made repeated attempts to prove it, so it would help if you let us know what you've tried.

Comment: I think your question already has an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313876/are-there-compact-manifolds-homotopy-equivalent-to-a-wedge-sum-of-compact-manifo?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there compact manifolds homotopy equivalent to a wedge sum of compact manifolds?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313876/are-there-compact-manifolds-homotopy-equivalent-to-a-wedge-sum-of-compact-manifo)